# Kinectproject with Nite Middleware and OpenNI throws Exceptions

Tags: java, kinect, openni, primesense

i have a problem with my Kinect. At the beginning i started only with OpenNI Samples, which works fine. Now i try to start with NITE and have some issues. If i run my code, Eclipse throws exceptions like this.

```
    Started context generating...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Method com.primesense.NITE.NativeMethods.xnvMessageListener_RegisterActivate(JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/OpenNI/OutArg;)I not found
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.primesense.NITE.NativeMethods.<clinit>(NativeMethods.java:13)
    at com.primesense.NITE.SessionManager.<init>(SessionManager.java:13)
    at GestureDetect.configNITE(GestureDetect.java:108)
    at GestureDetect.<init>(GestureDetect.java:59)
    at GestureDetect.main(GestureDetect.java:484)
```

OpenNI and NITE jar Files added to the build path... but it doesn't works :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! There is a incompatibility between the actual OpenNI and NITE Versions which can be downloaded from openni.org. OpenNI SDK v1.5.7.10 and NiTE v1.5.2.23 doesn't work together. Older versions are not available there :-(

The Solution is very simple. There is a all-around installer for OpenNI, NITE and SensorKinect, called ZigFuOpenNI. This Package included following versions.

OpenNI-Win32-1.3.2.3-Dev
NITE-Win32-1.4.1.2-Dev
SensorKinect-Win-OpenSource32-5.0.3.4

ZiFuOpenNi can be downloaded from

http://code.google.com/p/understanding-bones-kinect-exhibit/downloads/detail?name=ZigFuOpenNI.exe&can=2&q=

Works fine!